Formatting a VHD Disk (or any other disk) with Vds

I'm creating a virtual drive with CreateVirtualDisk.
I'm attaching it with AttachVirtualDisk.
I initialize it with IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK for a single GPT partition.
I create a single partition with IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX.

Now I have to format it with NTFS. I can use the FormatEx described in this question but this requires a mount point.
I tried instead ot use VDS. I got a IVdsServiceLoader , I queried for VDS_QUERY_VIRTUALDISK_PROVIDERS, and I found my attached disk as IVdsDisk.
However I don't know from this point how to format it. I saw that the  IVdsAdvancedDisk has the format options but I don't know how to get this interface.
Any other options?
As I found out, I can't format using DeviceIoControl.

but this requires a mount point. why, for what ?  you simply need pass to api valid win32 device path

you can use L"\\?\globalroot\Device\Harddisk\Partition" or L"\\?\globalroot\Device\HarddiskVolume" as 1-st parameter for FormatEx api require any DOS style drive name., not only drive letter style mount point

Thanks for your comments, I found it.

For anyone looking for a solution (error handling removed). The idea is to get the name from the Virtual Provider, then, when finding the same drive in the software proviver in a IVdsDisk, ask for an IVdsAdvancedDisk and perform the format.
 // Helper
template <typename T>
static int EnumObject(IEnumVdsObject* o,std::vector<CComPtr<T>>& res)
{
    int n = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        CComPtr<IUnknown> prov;
        ULONG uf = 0;
        o->Next(1, &prov, &uf);
        if (!prov)
            break;
        CComPtr<T> a;
        a = prov;
        if (!a)
            continue;
        res.push_back(a);
    }
    o->Reset();
    return n;
}

 // Vds Loading
 CComPtr<IVdsServiceLoader> sl;
 CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VdsLoader, 0, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IVdsServiceLoader), 
  (void**) & sl);
 CComPtr<IVdsService> pService = NULL;
 sl->LoadService(0,&pService);
 pService->WaitForServiceReady();

 // Enum providers
 CComPtr<IEnumVdsObject> pEnumVdsObject = NULL; 
 hr = pService->QueryProviders(VDS_QUERY_VIRTUALDISK_PROVIDERS | 
 VDS_QUERY_HARDWARE_PROVIDERS | VDS_QUERY_SOFTWARE_PROVIDERS, &pEnumVdsObject);

 // Check the Virtual Provider for the disk you have just created
EnumObject(pEnumVdsObject, VdsProviders);
std::wstring Diskname;
for (auto& v : VdsProviders)
{
    CComPtr<IEnumVdsObject> pEnumVdsObject2 = NULL;
    v->QueryVDisks(&pEnumVdsObject2);

    std::vector<CComPtr<IVdsVDisk>> disks;
    EnumObject(pEnumVdsObject2, disks);

    for (auto& disk : disks)
    {
        LPWSTR dn = 0;
        disk->GetDeviceName(&dn);

        if (dn)
            Diskname = dn;
    }
}

// Check the software provider for such a disk
for (auto& v : SwProviders)
{
    CComPtr<IEnumVdsObject> pEnumVdsObject2 = NULL;
    v->QueryPacks(&pEnumVdsObject2);

    std::vector<CComPtr<IVdsPack>> packs;
    EnumObject(pEnumVdsObject2, packs);

    for (auto& pack : packs)
    {
        if (1)
        {
            CComPtr<IEnumVdsObject> pEnumVdsObject3 = NULL;
            pack->QueryDisks(&pEnumVdsObject3);
            std::vector<CComPtr<IVdsDisk>> disks;
            EnumObject(pEnumVdsObject3, disks);

            for (auto& disk : disks)
            {
                VDS_DISK_PROP p = {};
                disk->GetProperties(&p);
                if (wcscmp(p.pwszDevicePath, Diskname.c_str()) == 0 && p.BusType == VDSBusTypeFileBackedVirtual)
                {
                    CComPtr<IVdsAdvancedDisk> ad;
                    ad = disk;
                    if (ad)
                    {
                        CComPtr<IVdsAsync> as;
                        HRESULT hr = 0;
                        hr = ad->FormatPartition(34 * SECTOR_SIZE, VDS_FST_NTFS,(LPWSTR)L"Label",SECTOR_SIZE,0,1,0,&as);
                        if (as)
                        {
                            VDS_ASYNC_OUTPUT ao = {};
                            as->Wait(&hr, &ao);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                R = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

